# PostWrite event using services according to an event's property

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have an EventSubscriberInterface called PostCreation listening to the POST_WRITE event.
The method called when the event occurs must call a service according to the "type" attribute of the object which the event occured on.

The following code is a working example of what I want:

```
<?php

class PostCreation implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $processAfterPostCreationTypeAService;
    private $processAfterPostCreationTypeBService;

    public function __construct(
        ProcessAfterPostCreationTypeAService $processAfterPostCreationTypeAService,
        ProcessAfterPostCreationTypeBService $processAfterPostCreationTypeBService
    ) {
        $this->processAfterPostCreationTypeAService = $processAfterPostCreationTypeAService;
        $this->processAfterPostCreationTypeBService = $processAfterPostCreationTypeBService;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::VIEW => ['processPostCreation', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE]];
    }

    public function processPostCreation(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event): void
    {
        $myObject = $event->getControllerResult();

        if (!$event->getRequest()->isMethod('POST') ||
            !$myObject instanceof MyClass
        ) {
            return;
        }

        /* some code */
        if($myObject->getType() === 'A') {
            $this->processAfterPostCreationTypeAService->doSomething($myObject);
        } else if($myObject->getType() === 'B') {
            $this->processAfterPostCreationTypeBService->doSomething($myObject);
        }
        /* some code */
    }
}
```

Doing it that way is not maintainable so I would like to find another solution, but I can't find it myself so I need help:

- The constructor of PostCreation can't know the object.type because it's called before the event occurs
- I can't instantiate easily ProcessAfterPostCreationTypeAService or ProcessAfterPostCreationTypeBService in processPostCreation method because they are services as well (and needs dependancy injection, configured to be autowired)

I'm sure dependancy injection could help me, but I can't find how.

So how to do something maintainable?

Comment: Take a look at [Service Locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html). It will take a bit of effort but you will end up injecting a ProcessServiceLocator with services indexed by your object's type.

Comment: Thank you, that's the thing I needed!